# How can I force dreamweaver to show CSS syntax highlighting for a PHP file?

Tags: php, css, syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver

this is my first ever question here.

Basically I have a dynamic CSS file, meaning the PHP changes the colours of borders and stuff depending on the preferences saved in  database. My problem is not code related but software related and that's why I think it deserves to be posted here over everywhere else.

My PHP file is all CSS, and the header sets the content type to text/css. Dreamweaver however, doesn't recognise the CSS, and prints it as straight text. No code highlighting, no auto-completion, the features I love and use dreamweaver for.

Can I force dreamweaver to use other syntax highlighting, for when PHP is outputting for other scenarios like mine?

Thanks!

Comment: I solved my own issue! I used a dirty hack to fool dreamweaver into thinking it was producing CSS in the PHP file. This is what I did, for all those trying to solve the issue too.

`<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    if(true==false):?>
        <style>
    <?php endif; ?>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya);
    body {
         margin:0px;
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         background-color:#222;`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, and it is better since it is easier to write and it doesn't use the php code  that makes no sense.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?> 
/* <style> /* notice that this entire line is a comment in CSS */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya); 
body { margin:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#222;
```